# Tracking Http405 codes with Azure AppInsights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm currently adding some monitoring to our application using Azure AppInsights and I would like to alert on 405 Method Not Allowed errors. I can't find any built in metrics for 405s. Is there a best practice, or easy way, to add this type of alerting? It is also useful if there is a way that is easily compatible with ARM templates since that's how we deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts by segmented metrics are not supported. Please vote for it at [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/13310073-support-alerting-on-a-segmented-filtered-metric).

You can implement this feature by using `ITelemetryProcessor` that will calculate all requests with the status code `405` and expose it as a separate metric.